# How can I catch an Exception inside a Controller for a Livewire Component

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am trying to catch a QueryException inside a livewire Controller. I want to render a different view when the database is not connected. This seems not to work since what am trying to fetch from the database is returned as null. The component is rendered regardless of whether I catch the Exception or not.

This is my function for fetching records and I have a view(dbConnection) inside the errors folder. I expect the view dbConnection inside the errors folder to be returned when the database is not connected.

```
class FetchPosts extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $featured = false;
    public $votes = false;
    public $latest = false;
    public function fetchRecords()
    {
      try{
        $topics = Topics::withCount(['topicComments', 'upVotes', 'downVotes']);
        if ($this->featured) {
        $topics->orderBy('topic_comments_count', 'desc')->orderBy('up_votes_count', 'desc');
        } elseif ($this->votes) {
        $topics->orderBy('up_votes_count', 'desc');
        }
        return $topics->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
      }
      catch(Throwable $e){
        return view('errors.dbConnection');
      }   
    }
    public function render()
    {
       return view('livewire.fetch-posts', ['topics' => $this->fetchRecords()]);
    }
}
```

After running the code:- this is the error I get

> Call to a member function count() on string.

This occurs from this line
`@if($topics->count())`

Comment: I don't find a line `@if($topics->count())`.

Comment: @greybeard I think he might be using a custom query scope filter. Peter, check you model function. the error is probably being thrown there. Also if you could update the question with a more detailed error trace, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the provided code closely.

A Livewire component renders a view with the parameter `topic` equal to the return value of the `fetchRecords` method of this Livewire component.

If the `try` block will execute without raising any exceptions, then this method will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections), which has the `count` method, and will render the Blade template without any errors. But if an exception will be caught, then the [view](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/%5BGlobal_Namespace%5D.html#function_view) function will be executed, and, according to the linked Laravel API reference, it will end up returning a string.

Thus, if the `fetchRecords` method doesn't catch an exception, then `$topics` will be a Collection, and the `$topics->count()` will get executed properly without errors. If `fetchRecords` method catches an exception, then `$topics` will be a string, which, of course, has no `count` method, and thus triggers an error.

Hope the behavior now makes sense for you!

To properly catch the exception, you will need to move the view logic to the `render` method, like this:

```
class FetchPosts extends Component
{
  use WithPagination;

  public bool $featured = false;
  public bool $votes = false;
  public bool $latest = false;

  public function fetchRecords()
  {
    try {
      $topics = Topics::withCount(['topicComments', 'upVotes', 'downVotes']);

      if ($this->featured) {
        $topics->orderBy('topic_comments_count', 'desc')->orderBy('up_votes_count', 'desc');
      } elseif ($this->votes) {
        $topics->orderBy('up_votes_count', 'desc');
      }

      return $topics->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    } catch(Throwable $e) {
      return false;
    }   
  }

  public function render()
  {
    $records = $this->fetchRecords();

    if($records instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator) {
      return view('livewire.fetch-posts', ['topics' => $records]);
    }

    return view('errors.dbConnection');
  }
}
```

So if you get an instance of a [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html), then you can be sure that all went well because it's exactly what the QueryBuilder's `paginate` method returns [according to the docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_paginate).

You can replace `false` returned on error with whatever you want on the `$records` variable of the `render` method in case if, for example, you would want to print an error's contents.

Comment: This explanation clearly explains this behavior. Any insights on how to catch the exception in the component? Regardless of this behavior?